# htaccess to redirect to a product page or index

Tags: .htaccess

I need htaccess directives that will

- if a page exists, load that page (ex: https://www.example.com/mypage.php )
- if no page specified, load the index page (ex: https://www.example.com/index.php )
- if the page is specified, but not found, go to a specific page and pass the page name as a query parameter (ex: https://www.example.com/1234 redirects to https://www.example.com/process.php?x=1234 ) (the process.php displays product number '1234')
- if all of the above don't work, go to the 404 page.

I'm a bit weak on htaccess and regex. I think this will work for #1 and #2:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d    
RewriteRule ^ - [L]    
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]    
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I think that an `errordocument` after the above rules will handle #4.
...but not sure how to do #3.

Am I close? Thanks.

Comment: There currently is no real difference between what you consider case #3, and #4. You need to first of all _specify_ what you would consider a valid “page” that should return an actual result here, and what is just a 404.

Comment: ...and the directives for case #3? (change www.example.com/1234 to www.example.com/process.php?x=1234 ?)

Comment: In case you wanted to catch anything that has just digits, something like `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ process.php?x=$1`